# How can I change the default directory for projects in an ssh git server?

Tags: git, ssh, git-server

Currently I would have to type

```
git clone ssh://git@<server_address>/home/git/<projectname>.git <projectname>
```

to be able to clone the project located at `/home/git/<projectname>` on the git server. But what If I knew that all my projects would be located in the home directory of the git user? Can I default git to use the home directory of the git user so that I would only have to type

```
git clone ssh://git@<server_address>:<projectname>.git
```

Comment: If it turns out that you can't do it, you could try using a symbolic link as a close enough solution

Comment: You cannot do that with syntax `ssh://git@<server_address>:<projectname>` because `ssh` [understands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls) `:<projectname>` as a port number. You can try scp-like syntax `git@<server_address>:<projectname>`

Comment: @phd bingo! that did it!

Comment: @phd if you don't mind, I'll add your comment to an answer to this question.

Comment: @Kalcifer No problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @phd, I was informed of the following solution:

The syntax that I used in my example

```
ssh://git@<server_address>:<projectname>
```

is incorrect, because `ssh` [understands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls) `:<projectname>` as a port number.

Using this scp-like syntax solves the issue:

```
git@<server_address>:<projectname>
```